# Applying for a Germany language course visa with a criminal record

Tags: visas, germany, applications, criminal-records

If I apply for a German language course visa and I have a criminal record related to drugs, for which I pleaded guilty and paid a fine instead of serving my sentence and completing my probation, will my visa application be denied?

My sentence began on August 30, 2021 and I was released from prison on November 4, 2021, after serving a sentence of 1 year and 6 months. I pleaded guilty and paid a fine instead of serving the full sentence, and I only spent 2 months in jail and completed probation to avoid going to jail. Is there a possibility of being approved if I apply for a German language course visa?

Comment: What was your sentence and when?  Convictions for drug-related crimes with prison sentences of more than say 2 years are typically unlikely to get a visa

Comment: August 30,2021 and i was released from prison on November 4, 2021, my sentence is 1 year and 6 months because I was plea bargaining I admitted to a low sentence and I am guilty instead of suffering in jail I paid a fine and I was released I only spent 2 months in jail and I did probation to avoid going to jail. Is there a possibility of being approved if I apply for a German language course visa? Can I apply for a long-term visa?

Comment: I assume you mean you were released in Nov 2022, not Nov 2021?

Comment: august 30,2021 when i was arrest and after 2 months November 4,2021 i was released from the jail and fine the sentence